# map and filter on observable return empty result

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I write an angular 12 application with rxjs that has a products categories list as a service stored in an observable, i am trying to create an observable that will return that categories that has an empty `parent_category_id`, the problem is that this observable returns an empty list.

this is my product category service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ProductCategory} from '../types/product';
import {Observable, Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductCategoriesService {

  private productCategories = new Subject<ProductCategory[]>();


  setProductCategories(pc: ProductCategory[]) {
    this.productCategories.next(pc);
  }

  get productCategories$(): Observable<ProductCategory[]> {
    return this.productCategories;
  }

  getRootProductCategories$(): Observable<ProductCategory[]> {
    return this.productCategories$.pipe(map((pc: ProductCategory[]) => pc.filter(p => p.parent_category_id === null)));
  }

}
```

in the component that displays the categories I created the following function:

```
 get getRootProductCategories$(): Observable<ProductCategory[]> {
    return this.pcService.getRootProductCategories$();
  }
```

and in it's view I have

```
<div id="product-categories">
  <app-product-category-card *ngFor="let rootProductCategories of getRootProductCategories$ | async"
               [url]="['/','products','X']" [title]="rootProductCategories.title"
                             img="XX">
  </app-product-category-card>

</div>
```

and i get no results.

now the problem is not with the filter rule, if i just type `true` in the filter rule it returns empty list.

if I change the function in the service to the following:

```
  getRootProductCategories$(): Observable<ProductCategory[]> {
    //return this.productCategories$.pipe(map((pc: ProductCategory[]) => pc.filter(p => p.parent_category_id === null)));
    return this.productCategories$.pipe();
  }
```

then I do get the full list of the categories, so I'm doing something wrong here I just don't know what.

any ideas ?

#updates

when I added tap() without json.stringify it returned something like this `[ [Object] [Object]...`, when I included `json.stringify()` it returns the proper object.

this is the code:

```
  getRootProductCategories$(): Observable<ProductCategory[]> {
    return this.productCategories$.pipe(tap(val => {
      console.log("Tap " + JSON.stringify(val));
    }),map((pc: ProductCategory[]) => pc.filter(p => p.parent_category_id === null)));
  }
```

this is the returned string:

```
Tap [{"id":1,"title":"מוצרי חשמל","description":"אלקטרוניקה","parent_category_id":null,"__typename":"ProductCategories"},{"id":2,"title":"לבית ולגן","description":"צינורות השקייה","parent_category_id":null,"__typename":"ProductCategories"},{"id":4,"title":"אביזרי רכב","description":null,"parent_category_id":null,"__typename":"ProductCategories"},{"id":5,"title":"קישוטי חיצוני","description":null,"parent_category_id":4,"__typename":"ProductCategories"},{"id":6,"title":"קישוט פנימי","description":null,"parent_category_id":4,"__typename":"ProductCategories"},{"id":3,"title":"4x4","description":null,"parent_category_id":5,"__typename":"ProductCategories"}]
```

Comment: Can you put a `tap` before the `map` method to log your data and append it to the post? Maybe `parent_category_id` is not `null` because your backend serializer turns it into a string or something like that.

Comment: filter() will keep all those records that match the predicate. In that case, if there are no elements with parent category NULL, then the list will be empty

Comment: @Fussel  thank you for your input, but as i stated if in the filter i just return true it still returns an empty list. i will add the  tap to see what's going on, but the filter rule is not the problem here

Comment: could it be you are missing a parenthsesis here `getRootProductCategories$ | async` ?

Comment: @chaimm - no. it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure about your observable and when you expect it to emit, but a possiblility is because you are using a `Subject` that only will emit when you do a `.next`. can you try switching it to a `BehaviorSubject`, that will emit whenever something subscribes to it. (although I don't know why adding a `.pipe()` would change that)

Comment: i didn't change anything besides changing the variable type to BehaviorSubject and it worked. thanks a lot